# Passing variable to AJAX XML GET

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, xpath

Trying to pull different nodes depending on which link a user clicks..
Problem I am having is passing the variable to Ajax.

Current Code:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <modules>
   <module id="1">
     <title>Title 1</title>
     <link>
        <Ltitle>A Sub title</Ltitle>
        <Lurl>http://www.alink.com</Lurl>
     </link>
   </module>
   <module id="2">
     <title>Title 2</title>
     <link>
        <Ltitle>A Sub title</Ltitle>
        <Lurl>http://www.alink.com</Lurl>
     </link>
   </module>
 </modules>
```

Html

```
<a href="#" rel="1">One</a>
<a href="#" rel="2">Two</a>
```

Jquery

```
var ajaxDataCollection = function(){
            var xmlSelect = $("a").attr('rel');
            alert(xmlSelect)
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "data.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find("module[id='+xmlSelect+']").each(function(){
                        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                        var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                        $('<li><h3>Module '+id+' :: <b>'+title+'</b></h3></li>').appendTo('.subMenu ul');
                        //<li><h3>Module 4 :: <b>Structures</b></h3></li>
                        $(this).find('link').each(function(){
                                    var Ltitle = $(this).find('Ltitle').text();
                                    var Lurl = $(this).find('Lurl').text();
                                    $('<li><a href="'+Lurl+'">'+Ltitle+'</a>').appendTo('.subMenu ul');
                                    //<li><a href="#">Bonjour</a></li>
                                });
                    });
                }
            });
        };
        ajaxDataCollection();
```

Comment: you mean you are not getting the xml response? or you are having trouble parsing the result? did the `success` handler get called?

Comment: @3nigma, everything works fine if I don't pass a variable ie: $(xml).find("module[id='1']") but I would like to put a variable where "1" is so I can dynamically pull nodes (if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume that you are getting the xml response, use `.parseXML` to parse xml, wrapping the xml response in `$` and accessing it using the DOM traversal methods is not very cross browser, i have created a fiddle hope that will help

http://jsfiddle.net/r4SBr/